# Using shell-command-on-region with TRAMP

Tags: tramp, shell-command

I like to use `shell-command-on-region` for pretty printing a selected region of code with *prettier*.

After selecting a region, I type `C-u M-|` and then I use `prettier --parser ruby` as the shell command. This is working great. :)

Now, I also like to use TRAMP to open a ruby file on a remote system.

Unfortunately, `shell-command-on-region` does not seem to respect TRAMP. It attempts to execute a shell command on my local machine.

On the other hand, if I invoke `shell-command` unsing `M-!`, this executes a command on the remote machine.

Is there a way to make `shell-command-on-region` work together with TRAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell-command-on-region` uses `call-process-region`, which doesn't support remote execution.